# RealityKit – Why ModelEntity doesn't change dynamically?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, realitykit

I am building an AR App.
Here is my code

Content View:

```swift
@State var timeAccumulate = 0
let styleCount = 2
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
var body: some View {
let vc = ARViewContainer(timeAccumulate: timeAccumulate)
   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   .onAppear(perform: { getData() })
   .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        timeAccumulate = (timeAccumulate + 1) % styleCount
   }
   return vc
}
```

ARViewContainer:

```swift
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var timeAccumulate: Int
    let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
    let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        
        arView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        for i in 1...(imageOrder.count+1-1) {
            let entity = boxAnchor.findEntity(named: "box\(i)")!
       
            let modelEntity = entity.children[0]
            modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            arView.installGestures([.all], for: modelEntity as! Entity & HasCollision)
        }
        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        return arView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        print(timeAccumulate)
        for i in 1...(imageOrder.count+1-1) {
            let boxThis = boxAnchor.findEntity(named: "box\(i)")!
            var modelEntity: ModelEntity!

            if timeAccumulate == 0 {
                modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "Box", in: Bundle.main)
                boxThis.children[0] = modelEntity
            } else {
                modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "Chess1", in: Bundle.main)
                boxThis.children[0] = modelEntity
            }
            do {
                var material = SimpleMaterial()
                
                let location = documents.appendingPathComponent("\(i).jpg")
                let tre = try TextureResource.load(contentsOf: location, withName: "\(i).jpg")
                material.baseColor = try MaterialColorParameter.texture(tre)
                
                material.roughness = .float(0.0)
                
                (modelEntity as Entity & HasModel).model?.materials = [material]
            }catch{
                //print("no image", count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want 25 boxes to transform into another model every ten seconds, the box, then the chess, then the box, then the chess

I am sure that parameter timeAccumulate is working, it is 0, then 1, then 0, then 1.

But the view does not change. It's always been a box.

What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the following errors and it will do the trick:

1. Use `$` for `timeAccumulate` property wrapper in `ContentView` struct to get a binding struct.

   ```
   ARViewContainer(timeAccumulate: $timeAccumulate)
   ```
2. Then use `@Binding` attribute for `timeAccumulate` property in `ARViewContainer` struct.

   ```
   @Binding var timeAccumulate: Int
   ```
3. `baseColor` is still working in iOS 15 but it'll be irrelevant on iOS 16. So, use `color` instead:

   ```
   var material = SimpleMaterial()

   material.color = .init(tint: .white,
                       texture: .init(try! .load(named: "texture.png")))
   ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I tried it, and it's successfully jumped into function updateUIView(), also If I print timeAccumulate there, it is correct, but the model on the screen is still box. What should I do? thanks

Comment: Everything works fine, if you change the range of both loops from `1...(imageOrder.count+1-1)` to `1...3`, for instance. Also, test timer with `2` seconds interval. And I see that you are changing Box to Box, is it right?

Comment: Hi, I finally found that If I add @Binding also add these two lines in updateView function ARVariables.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll() then ARVariables.arView.scene.anchors.append(newAnchor), it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is setting timeAccumulate to the first value of the @State one. Try to make you `var timeAccumulate: Int` Binding so that it could listen to changes from your @State variable.

```
@Binding var timeAccumulate: Int
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I tried it, and it's successfully jumped into function updateUIView(), also If I print timeAccumulate there, it is correct, but the model on the screen is still box. What should I do? thanks

Comment: I suggest you remove the old model and add the new one.

Comment: Hi, I finally found that If I add @Binding also add these two lines in updateView function ARVariables.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll() then ARVariables.arView.scene.anchors.append(newAnchor), it works! Thank you.